# Equation solving with nonnegativity constraint

Tags: equation-solving

I try to solve the following equation.

```
eq1 = -((2*Subscript[V, 2]*(Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]^3 - \[Theta]*(4*\[Theta] + Sqrt[Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]*(8*\[Theta] + Subscript[\[Alpha], 2])]) + 
       Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]^2*(10*\[Theta] + Sqrt[Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]*(8*\[Theta] + Subscript[\[Alpha], 2])]) + \[Theta]*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]*
        (-1 + 12*\[Theta] + 6*Sqrt[Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]*(8*\[Theta] + Subscript[\[Alpha], 2])])))/(Sqrt[Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]*(8*\[Theta] + Subscript[\[Alpha], 2])]*
      (2*\[Theta] + Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + Sqrt[Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]*(8*\[Theta] + Subscript[\[Alpha], 2])])^2)) == 0
```

So I used the solve command.

```
Solve[eq1, Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]]
```

This gives four roots of equation 1 which are too long to represent.
Here, I have a quesiton about the method of solving equation with nonnegativity constraint.
If I only want to see the postive value of alpah_2, is there any way to do solve this equation with constraint that alpah_2 greater than or equal to zero?

Comment: You could do somthing like `Simplify[Solve[eq1, Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]],Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]]` , probably additional assumptions for the parameters are necessary!

Comment: Let me recommend you not to use subscripts in your calculations. They are prone to errors. Even worse, sometimes the calculations with subscripts return correct results, but sometimes - fail.

Comment: A common way to enforce non-negativity constraints would be to replace `Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]` with `Exp[a2]` and solve for `a2`.